# formatting table using php

Tags: php, html

Im having trouble formatting a table using php, this is just part of my code

```
    echo"<th>Name:</th> <td>".$row['firstName'] . "</td> ";
    echo"<th>Last Name:</th> <td>".$row['lastName'] . "</td> ";
```

the way its formatting is the following 
Name: Israel       Last Name: Rodriguez

The way i want it formatted is the following 
Name:             Last Name:
Israel              Rodriguez

any help is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You messed up rows definition, try change your code like this:

```
echo"<tr><th>Name:</th><th>Last Name:</th></tr>";
echo"<tr> <td>".$row['firstName'] . "</td><td>".$row['lastName'] . "</td></tr>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly understand a html table layout first. Then just `echo` the text as you want in `php`

### HTML Table layout

example for - 2 columns, 2 rows + a header

```
<table>
     <tr>  <!-- table Header, this row will look bold by default -->
          <th></th>
          <th></th>
     </tr>

     <!-- Normal data rows follow -->
     <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
     </tr>
</table>
```